# Looking for a way to get PyCUDA with default MacOS NVIDIA drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, cuda

I have a CUDA NVIDIA card ( GeForce GT 750 M) and I would like to use the default NVIDIA drivers of MacOS to be able to install PyCUDA like I did with NVIDIA drivers.

Is it possible ? For the moment, I get in Python shell :

```
>>> import pycuda.autoinit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda/autoinit.py", line 5, in <module>
    cuda.init()
pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuInit failed:
```

Any help is welcome, I don't know how to install pycuda with default MacOS drivers

Comment: You might find the answer in this long [post](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025945/cuda-setup-and-installation/mac-cuda-driver-fully-compatible-with-macos-high-sierra-10-13-error-/1).

Comment: @harrymc . Thanks, it seems that, after installing web drivers (native MacOS NVIDIA driver), one has to reboot multiple times before one could import "pycuda.autoinit".

Comment: Was this action motivated by my link?

Comment: yes, from what it is said on your link, we may have to reboot multiple times

Comment: Should I put up an answer?

Comment: yes if you want to get the award, have you personaly experimented this issue ?

Comment: I added an answer. Feel free to edit my answer and add details about what exactly you did, for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is about the problem of correctly installing the NVIDIA CUDA driver:
[MAC CUDA driver fully compatible with macOS High Sierra 10.13 (error](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025945/cuda-setup-and-installation/mac-cuda-driver-fully-compatible-with-macos-high-sierra-10-13-error-).

This very long post contains much advice about installing the default MacOS driver in order to get pyCuda (python with NVIDIA GPU) working,
including what worked or didn't work for some users.
Most posts underline the importance of rebooting after each and every step.

For the poster here, the advice to reboot at least twice was the missing clue
which allowed him to advance in the installation.